# SimpleXML throwing warnings - how to catch?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having some trouble determining what's going on with `simplexml_load_string()`  I'm using the below code to render some XML.... when I run this code I get error messages like:

```
Message: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 94: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 15 and head
```

Any ideas on how I can catch these warnings?  `libxml_get_errors` has no affect.

```
                $response = simplexml_load_string($response);
                var_dump($response);
                if (count(libxml_get_errors()) > 0) {
                    print_r(libxml_get_errors());
                }

                if (is_object($response)) { //returns true when warnings are thrown
                    //process response
                } else {
                    //record error
                }
```

Comment: You are loading an invalid .xml file. Maybe delegate the problem to the guy which is providing it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // !!!

$elem = simplexml_load_string($xml);
if($elem !== false)
{
    // Process XML structure here
}
else
{
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error)
    {
        error_log('Error parsing XML file ' . $file . ': ' . $error->message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't prevent the warnings, it just displays more information about the errors. To prevent the warnings, use `set_error_handler()` as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012247/204842

Comment: The error handling is even worse. The warning gives more specific messages about wrong xml source part than the error handling can give. The latter only show column, line which is hard to locate the error part if the xml source file is not coded in well format.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution, in **PHP** you can ignore any error messages usign the error control operator(`@`), in this case:

```php
$data = @simplexml_load_string($xml);
if ($data === false) { // catch error!
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

> Check this doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

*Good luck!*

Answer (score 0):

In my situation server which was sharing XML changed their http to https. Because of that we were downloading old path XML file, which in this case was "corrupted". That is why we had the error.

XML files was loading perfectly because of that i didn't noticed https problem ( browser redirect ).